# Weird data formats for import to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, data-import

I have received a set of data from a third party. Each dataset contains 4 files, respectively:

```
***.CTL
***.dat
***_post.sql
***_pre.sql
```

I was tasked to import those datasets into our SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I had a brief look into one of the sql files and noticed that "VARCHAR2()" data type is used. Could it be Oracel data?

Anyone familiar with the formats and how to import them into MS SQL Server?

The CTL file looks like:

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'YVW_DDC_NDWHYDRANTS_DDC.dat'
APPEND INTO TABLE "NDWHYDRANTS_DDC"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '$$' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
( 
NDW_CLASS, 
CSSCLASSNAME, 
G3E_GEOMETRY COLUMN OBJECT 
( sdo_gtype INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
  sdo_srid INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
   isnull FILLER CHAR, 
  SDO_POINT COLUMN OBJECT  NULLIF G3E_GEOMETRY.isnull="pt" 
  ( X INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
    Y INTEGER EXTERNAL, 
    Z INTEGER EXTERNAL), 
  SDO_ELEM_INFO VARRAY terminated by ';' 
    (SDO_ORDINATES char(38)), 
  SDO_ORDINATES VARRAY terminated by ':' 
    (SDO_ORDINATES char(38))) , 
G3E_FID, 
G3E_FNO, 
UNIQUE_ID, 
TYPE, 
OWNER_ID, 
OWNER_FSC, 
RESP_AUTH, 
CONST_DATE, 
RESP_DEVELOPER, 
WARRANTY_EXP_DATE, 
FMS_FILE_REFERENCE, 
SYS_STATE, 
SYS_DATE_CREATE, 
SYS_DATE_LAST_MOD, 
AMG_X, 
AMG_Y, 
ASSET_OWNER, 
HEIGHT )
```

The xxx_pre.sql data looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE "NDWHYDRANTS_DDC" ( 
NDW_CLASS VARCHAR2(1), 
CSSCLASSNAME VARCHAR2(50), 
G3E_GEOMETRY MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY, 
G3E_FID FLOAT NOT NULL, 
G3E_FNO NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE_ID FLOAT, 
TYPE VARCHAR2(80), 
OWNER_ID FLOAT, 
OWNER_FSC VARCHAR2(255), 
RESP_AUTH VARCHAR2(50), 
CONST_DATE FLOAT, 
RESP_DEVELOPER VARCHAR2(50), 
WARRANTY_EXP_DATE FLOAT, 
FMS_FILE_REFERENCE VARCHAR2(50), 
SYS_STATE VARCHAR2(9), 
SYS_DATE_CREATE FLOAT, 
SYS_DATE_LAST_MOD FLOAT, 
AMG_X FLOAT, 
AMG_Y FLOAT, 
ASSET_OWNER VARCHAR2(40), 
HEIGHT FLOAT );
```

Comment: VARCHAR2 definitely smells like Oracle. If you want to know if anyone is familiar with the formats, you'll need to show us some samples. We can't guess what the data looks like based solely on file extension.

Comment: Thanks. File samples added.

Comment: Yikes, most of that should be easy translation, but for a few things, good luck. No such thing as `VARRAY` in SQL Server, for example, and I have no idea how compatible the two systems' geometry types are. Is there a reason you are trying to use SQL Server to import table structures that are clearly designed for Oracle?

Comment: My company uses SQL Server not Oracle. So it must be stored (imported) to SQL Server.

Comment: Well whatever app is expecting to use these tables is not going to be easy to switch - I honestly have no idea how you're going to store varray data or how the app or its interfaces will have to change to deal with it...

Comment: Thanks for the those info. I know it's going to be pretty hard to make the switch... ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61813/discussion-between-alextc-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: Way late to the game but I spent the last 8+ years working in Oracle performing data conversions into Oracle... we used Control Files (CTL) and Oracle's SQL Loader executable to load the data.  The process is to run SQL Loader and it knows what to do with the data based on the CTL file...  We saved our delimited data in .txt files but regardless of where the data is the control file(s) tell Oracle what to do with the data as well as tell the Loader how the data is formatted.